# Parse XML to a picture using JEuclid

Tags: math, javafx-2, latex, javafx-8, tex

In [the official site of SnuggleTex](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/snuggletex/documentation/overview-and-features.html) they wrote:

> SnuggleTeX has optional features for converting the resulting MathML to images (using the JEuclid library) and can additionally attempt to convert very simple MathML expressions into a mixture of XHTML and CSS.

How can I parse an xmlString to a picture using [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/)?

This is my code :

```
/* Create vanilla SnuggleEngine and new SnuggleSession */
        SnuggleEngine engine = new SnuggleEngine();
        SnuggleSession session = engine.createSession();

/* Parse some very basic Math Mode input */
        SnuggleInput input = new SnuggleInput("$$ x+2=3 $$");
        session.parseInput(input);

/* Convert the results to an XML String, which in this case will
 * be a single MathML <math>...</math> element. */
        String xmlString = session.buildXMLString();
        MathMLParserSupport.parseString(xmlString);
    JEuclidUtilities.createWebPageOptions(true,new MathMLImageSavingCallback() {
      @Override
      public String getImageContentType(int i) {
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public File getImageOutputFile(int i) {
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public OutputStream getImageOutputStream(int i) {
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public String getImageURL(int i) {
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public MutableLayoutContext getLayoutContext(int i) {
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void imageSavingSucceeded(Object o, int i, String s) {

      }

      @Override
      public void imageSavingFailed(Object o, int i, String s, Throwable throwable) {

      }
  });
```

I don't know how to parse the xmlString to an image.

Comment: http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/snuggletex/documentation/legacy-web-pages.html looks like a step-by-step instruction for what you need.

Comment: it's not really step by step I didn't understand. now my code looks  like in the question and I don't know how to display the pic in javafx imageview.